# Numerical higher order derivatives with R

Tags: r, numerical

I need to calculate third and fourth order numerical derivatives in R. I suppose I should use the grad (or hessian) function from the numDeriv package recursively but I have problems with evaluation. What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: You should describe your data situation better, ideally by posting dput( for an adequate fragment of your data object).

Comment: Don't do it.  Numerical derivatives are extremely sensitive to  noise, so by the time you get to  `f'''(x)` the results are rather untrustworthy.  At the very least, you need to have a really good method for removing noise prior to differentiating each time.